# How to format Blogger blog for Instant Articles?

Tags: blogger, facebook-instant-articles

[image]
I just implemented instant articles for my blogger blog. But I keep getting only the title and image? Why is not loading my body content?

Comment: What have you tried? You have to provide more Information. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood what was wrong with my blogger blog. I was not getting the body text because it needed to be surrounded by <p> tag. I've compiled all the other steps here - https://amprandom.blogspot.com/2017/08/instant-articles-for-blogspot.html